# Changing my screen resolution

Tags: resolution

I have a new laptop which has a screen resolution of 3840 x 2160. Yesterday I installed Ubuntu on the machine. The icons and taskbar and text etc. are really small and I want to make them bigger.

I know I can do this just by changing the resolution in the settings until I find a display I am happy with, but I'm wondering if that's the best way to do it or whether there is a more appropriate way.

Comment: This has been answered over on AskUbuntu [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/472262/adapt-ubuntu-to-a-high-dpi-resolution-screen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your distribution, but if you installed Ubuntu 14.04 or similar with the Unity desktop, you can go to `Unity Control Center` > `Displays` > `Scale for menu and title bars` which will set the scale of items rather than the resolution. Unfortunately, you would have to do more than just that to achieve scaling, and even then, not all applications will scale. It's more of a hacky way to do it.

On my Windows machine, I fixed this by just sizing down the resolution. On many operating systems, UI items become pixelated or blurred when scaled up, and whenever this is the case, setting the screen resolution is usually the most appropriate way to go.